# How to overlay 2 divs inside a table cell

Tags: html, css

I haver the following code:

```
<td class="mobile-user-icon">
    <span class="mobile-photo">background text</span>
    <span class="mobile-caller-mute">overlay text</span>
</td>

.mobile-user-icon {
    width: 64px;
    height: 64px;
    text-align: center;
    background: grey;
    color: white;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
```

I want to overlay `mobile-caller` on `mobile-photo`, whilst maintaining `vertical-align:middle` for the 2 text elements.

I know if this wasn't in a table, the usual way to do this is to set the parent `mobile-user-icon` to `position:relative`, and then `position:absolute` both child elements with the same absolute position.

However, this does not work in a `table-cell`. Any ideas?

JS Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mFNed/1/

Comment: Have you tried wrapping the two spans in another tag, like a paragraph, then set position: relative for the paragraph and position: absolute for the spans?

Comment: Where's your CSS rule for mobile-photo and mobile-caller-mute? Not done yet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add a relative position to `.mobile-user-icon`:

```
.mobile-user-icon {
    width: 64px;
    height: 64px;
    text-align: center;
    background: grey;
    color: white;
    vertical-align: middle;
    position: relative;
}
```

Since you have a fixed height for the table cell, you can easily use the CSS `line-height` option to maintain vertical alignment. Set the following CSS for the `<span>` elements inside `.mobile-user-icon`:

```
.mobile-user-icon > span {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    vertical-align: middle;
    line-height: 64px;
}
```

[<kbd>**jsFiddle Demo**</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/qVkT9/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Adding a float:left style to your cells should work.

check the following link I have updated your fiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/mFNed/5/

```
.mobile-caller-mute {
    float:left;    
}
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to overlay the two elements, it just places them one after the other. See the question: *I want to overlay `mobile-caller` on `mobile-photo`, whilst maintaining `vertical-align:middle` for the 2 text elements.*